# Getting error while implementing Code First modal in asp.net MVC application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.0, code-first

I have created a sample MVC application from here:

[**CLICK HERE**](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

I am using Visual Studio 2010 IDE.
See the ***Setting the Connection String***  section.

Instead of SQL Server Compact Edition I want to directly work with SQL Server 2008 that is installed on my system so when I put following connection string in web.config i got an error message:

```
<add name="SchoolContext" connectionString="server=(local);database=School;user id=sa;password=1234;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

[image]

How to resolve this error?

Comment: How many instances model db context do you create before you get a list of of students ? Where do you create your model db ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the School database already exist? If so, delete it and let Code First recreate it.